# What is the difference between `state` and `const`?

Tags: perl, readonly-variable

It seems similar to write:

```perl
use Const::Fast;
const $xx, 77;
sub test {
    do_something_with( $xx );    
}
```

or

```perl
sub test {
    state $xx =  77;
    do_something_with( $xx );    
}
```

What is the better way to accomplish this: via `const` or via `state`?

```perl
sub get_ip_country {
    my ($ip_address) = @_;
    my $ip_cc_database = GeoIP2::Database::Reader->new(file => '/etc/project/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');
    ...
}
```

**UPD**
At this sub I do not change pointer togeoip database, so it should be `const`. But I not want recreate object each time when sub is called (this is slow). So I suppose it will be faster to use `state`, despite pointer is not changed.

It seems it should be `const state $ip_cc_database`

Comment: `state` does not create a read only variable.

Comment: I don't think they have the same funcionality.  [state](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Persistent-variables-via-state()) creates a variable that persist between function calls (and the value can change) and [const](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast) create read-only variables.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: `GeoIP2::Database::Reader->new()` creates object

Comment: @EugenKonkov Yeah, but they are all objects in a sense. Re: `const state`: I don't think that works. Try it out but I don't think so. Since it's expensive to create the object, I'd go for `state` - or make a new class, containing a `const  $ip_cc_database` that you instantiate  with `state`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They do not do the same thing.

- `state` declares a variable that will only be initialized the first time you enter the function. It's  mutable though, so you can change its value, but it will keep the value between calls to the same function. This program would for example print `78` and `79`:

  ```
  sub test {
      state $xx = 77;     # initialization only happens once
      print ++$xx . "\n"; # step the current value and print it
  }
  test; # 78
  test; # 79
  ```
- `const` declares an immutable (readonly) variable that, if declared in a function, would be reinitialized every time the function is called.

Comment: What is the best choice to use instead `my` at my example?

Comment: @EugenKonkov I'm afraid that's not possible to tell from your example. You'll have to decide from the differences between `state` and `const` and decide from that. Is it supposed to be a constant (readonly) variable or not? If it's not supposed to be a constant, make it `const`. `state` as you can see is used for keeping state between calls to a function. Not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a value that is constant, then you should use something like [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast).

But if you want a value that can be changed, but which retains its value between calls to a function, then you need a [state variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state).

So running, this:

```
sub test {
  state $x = 1;

  say $x++;
}

test() for 1 .. 10;
```

Gives this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But running this:

```
use Const::Fast;

sub test {
  const my $x, 1;

  say $x++;
}

test() for 1 .. 10;
```

Gives a runtime error:

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted at const_test line 12.
```

Comment: What is the best choice to use instead `my` at my example?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: If your value is constant, then use a constant. If it varies, then use a variable.

Comment: I updated question. It does not varies, but I do not want recreate object each time when sub is called.

Answer (score 1):

As @TedLyngmo points out in a comment to your OP, `const state` is not valid Perl.  `const` is a pragma, so works at compile time, while `state` is a runtime construct.

In terms of your efficiency requirement, that the `GeoIP2::Database::Reader` constructor is called only once, either will work.  If you further want it to be read-only so that you cannot inadvertently invalidate the reference, you can still use both.  `const` does it for you automatically, but you can duplicate that behavior with `state` with a layer of indirection:

```
sub ip_cc_database {
   state $db = GeoIP2::Database::Reader->new(file => '/etc/project/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');
}
sub get_ip_country {
    my ($ip_address) = @_;
    my $ip_cc_database = ip_cc_database();
    ...
}
```

The answer to your question about when to use one over the other is a bit more nuanced.

The real difference between the two approaches is when the constructor is called. Using `const` it's during the compile phase, with `state` it's during runtime.

If you're application *always* calls `get_ip_country`, and you don't care about amortizing startup costs over the lifetime of the process, `const` is simpler.

However, if you don't always call `get_ip_country`, and creating the `GeoIP2::Database::Reader` object is expensive, then using `state` means you only pay for that cost if you need it.

There's also the user experience to consider. If your program is interactive or if it starts generating output before you need to call `get_ip_country`, delaying creating the object until its actually needed means your program doesn't just sit there seemingly doing nothing until all of the startup has completed.